# Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION not recognized

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm creating an Android project with Eclipse and I'm getting that error.
I'm using Gingerbread 2.3.3 (Google API Level 10).
What could be missing?

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import android.hardware.Sensor ?

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact, only new sensors are not recognized, weird. I mean, LINEAR_ACCELERATION, ROTATIONAL_MATRIX (I don't remember the exact names right now). I know they are a fusion of sensors...I mean sensors as they are inside Sensor class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an import. I was using the

> import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.Sensor; 
>   import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorEvent; 
>   import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorEventListener; 
>   import org.openintents.sensorsimulator.hardware.SensorManagerSimulator;

from the openintents project which needed an import that was conflicting to use the Sensor class and then I couldn't use the new Sensors.

Thanks. Guillermo.